# Get RD user client hostname in Server 2012 R2 RD deployment

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, hostname, remote-desktop-services

There is currently nowhere in the server manager GUI that I can see, that shows me the hostname of the machine a user is using to log onto our remote desktop deployment.

I have had a quick look through the powershell commandlets included with 2012 R2, but cannot find anyway to get the hostname for each connection.

Is it possible to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

The event log of the RD server will list the IP address of the connection. If you're using any sort of proxy server such as Remote Desktop Gateway, you will likely have to correlate log entries between the RD server and the proxy/Gateway to get the user's true IP address.